# Does slave bind9 DNS server answer with dhcpd DDNS updates included?

Tags: bind, ddns, dhcpd, slave, master

When I set up ISC dhcpd with a primary and secondary as failover and I have bind9 set up as master/slave and I configure the dhcpd so that it sends the ddns updates also to the slave dns that is set up to forward the updates to the master.  If the master dns server is down and the slave has accepted the updates from dhcpd but did not yet forward the updates to the master dns server, will the slave dns server answer with these ddns updates included or will it wait and answer using the "old" data until the master is up again and the master has feeded the updates to the slave?

In short, if the master dns is down and the slave dns waits answering with the ddns updates included until the master is back again, then updating the slave dns from dhcpd does not seem to make any sense for me.

Thanks a lot.

luzze